# I need to remove Z dimension on spatial column (ST_GEOMETRY) with Esri on Oracle using the PL/SQL packages

Tags: oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, z-value, sdo-geometry

I need to remove Z dimension on spatial column (ST_GEOMETRY) with Esri on Oracle using the PL/SQL packages

I need to do the following, but using the ESRI PL/SQL packages on Oracle.

I have used a couple of the packages such as SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_OPERATORS, however I am unsure if doing the below (removing Z) is possible in PL/SQL.

There are directions of how to do this in ArcMap:

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010389

- Browse to ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Geodatabase.
- Open the Feature Class to Geodatabase (multiple) tool.
- Add all the feature classes into the Input Feature Class parameter.
- Select an Output Geodatabase.
- Click the Environments button at the bottom of the tool dialog box.
- Expand the General Settings.
- For the parameter, Output has Z Values, change the value to Disabled.
- For the parameter, Output has M Values, change the value to Disabled.
- Click OK in the Environments dialog box.
- Click OK to execute the geoprocessing tool.

How can I do the equivalent in PL/SQL?

Comment: That is what I want to do. I am trying to ETL esri tables into an oracle data warehouse with sdo_geometries through an oracle db_link.

Comment: Also I have an oracle plsql function which will convert the st_geometry into a wkt well know text.  I also have another plsql function to pull the wkt clob through the dblink.   The only thing I could not get via plsql was the conversion to a tableau (resorting) friendly 2d layer.

Comment: I meant reporting tool friendly ( such as tableau ) by removing the z dimension

Comment: My experience with Z-enabled feature classes has been that the Z values are often in the feature classes by mistake; they're not actually used. Do you have the option of asking the data owner to remove the Z-dimension from the feature classes?

Comment: I have reporting tools such as Tableau and Thoughtspot.  They only use 2D geometries.  That is why I hope to remove the Z attributes.  I am not sure if Oracle can accept the ESRI exported Z WKT's (Well known text).  I have a regex expression to remove the z dimensions from the string, but I would MUCH prefer do it with pl/sql via a transform type of function ...such as ESRI's sde.st_transform(shape,4269)    or 
    Oracle's SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SHAPE,4269)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a test SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polyline feature class that has Z coordinates. This is what the WKT text looks like:

```
select
    sde.st_astext(shape)
from
    st_geom_z


SDE.ST_ASTEXT(SHAPE)                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------
LINESTRING Z ( 0.0 0.0 1.0, 10.0 20.0 2.0, 30.0 40.0 3.0)
                        ^              ^              ^
```

You'll notice that the WKT has a " Z  " in the prefix: `LINESTRING Z ()`. I don't think Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY supports that syntax. I think it needs it to be like this: `LINESTRING ()`.

---

Steps:

1. We can remove the `Z` from the WKT string using the REPLACE function.
2. Then we can convert the WKT to SDO_GEOMETRY.

   - Unfortunately, ST_GEOMETRY doesn't have a function for removing Z coordinates from geometries. So we'll do it using SDO_GEOMETRY instead.
3. We'll remove the Z's from the SDO_GEOMETRY using the SDO_CS.MAKE_2D function.

<sup>.</sup>

```
select
  sdo_cs.make_2d(
    sdo_geometry(
      replace(upper(sde.st_astext(shape)),'LINESTRING Z','LINESTRING'))) sdo_geom_no_z
from
  st_geom_z

SDO_GEOM_NO_Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
------------------
SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(0, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40))
```

Now, the SDO_GEOMETRY vertices only have X&Y coordinates, not Z.

```
SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_GEOM_NO_Z)                                          
------------------------------------------
LINESTRING (0.0 0.0, 10.0 20.0, 30.0 40.0)
```

Note: That query will also remove M-values too (not just Z values).

---

Related:

- [SDO_CS.MAKE_2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/SDO_CS-reference.html#GUID-EC9756BC-76D9-4A59-A51C-9BB13FCC0B65) (and an [example](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16832389/#Comment_16832389))
- [Convert M-enabled SDE.ST_GEOMETRY to SDO_GEOMETRY using SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428735/convert-m-enabled-sde-st-geometry-to-sdo-geometry-using-sql)
- [Idea: Support ‘MULTILINESTRING M’ WKT syntax (SDO_GEOMETRY)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4497275/idea-support-multilinestring-m-wkt-syntax)
- [Idea: Support M-enabled WKB (SDO_GEOMETRY)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4497379/idea-support-m-enabled-wkb)
- [Idea: ST_GEOMETRY function to remove M and/or Z coordinates from geometries](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/st-geometry-function-to-remove-m-and-or-z/idi-p/1164490)