# ST_GEOMETRY feature class: Add a hidden SDO_GEOMETRY column

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, st-geometry, sdo-geometry

I have an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY FC in an Oracle 18c EGDB. I want to use Oracle Spatial functions on the data (calculate polyline midpoint, M-values, dynamic segmentation, etc.).

Ideally, I'd convert the shape column in the table to SDO_GEOMETRY. But that's not possible due to dependencies on the data.

---

I've explored converting from ST_GEOMETRY to SDO_GEOMETRY *on-the-fly* in a query.

```
--Source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/429145/62572
select
    objectid,
    --Oracle misinterprets the Ms as Zs. So we need to change the GTYPE after-the-fact (from 3006 to 3306).
    sdo_geometry(a.shape.sdo_gtype + 300,
                 a.shape.sdo_srid,
                 a.shape.sdo_point,
                 a.shape.sdo_elem_info,
                 a.shape.sdo_ordinates) as shape
from
    (
    select
        cast(objectid as number(38,0)) as objectid,
        --Oracle doesn't support the 'LINESTRING M' WKT syntax
        sdo_geometry(replace(sde.st_astext(shape),'LINESTRING M','LINESTRING'),sde.st_srid(shape)) shape 
    from
        my_st_geom_fc
    ) a
```

That query  works, but the conversion is complicated and slow. I don't want to do that conversion every time a user queries the data.

---

As an alternative, I'm considering adding a hidden SDO_GEOMETRY column to the table:

1. Using SQL, add an additional geometry column (SDO_GEOMETRY) called SDO_GEOM.

   - The column wouldn't be registered in the system tables as the FC's true shape column. It would just be an extra column; hopefully ArcGIS would just ignore it.
2. I'd create a trigger that would automatically populate the column after an INSERT, or after an UPDATE to the ST_GEOMETRY column. I'd use the logic in the query mentioned above. So the two columns would always be in sync.

---

Would that extra geometry column cause any problems in the enterprise geodatabase (10.7.1) or in ArcGIS Pro (2.9.2)?

Related: [Where do the docs say we can only have a single geometry column per table?](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/only-a-single-geometry-column-per-table/td-p/1175726)

Comment: Wow, just ***soooo*** unsupported. Even if it did work (which I doubt), there's no saying if it will continue to work with the next DLL patch. Why not create a parallel materialized view instead?

Comment: @Vince Good idea about the materialized view. I mentioned the MV idea, and other ideas in this Esri Community post: [ST_GEOMETRY FC: Options for using Oracle Spatial functions](https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/st-geometry-fc-options-for-using-oracle-spatial/m-p/1169587).

Comment: @Vince I wonder if an INVISIBLE column might be an option. I would explicitly select the column in queries. And yet, it'd be invisible to ArcGIS, so it wouldn't cause problems. [Invisible Columns in Oracle Database](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/invisible-columns-12cr1). Thoughts?

Comment: How many INVISIBLE columns do you think have been tested in Redlands? I expect that will fall in the "Good luck with that" support class.

Comment: My thoughts are: invisible columns were designed to be hidden from existing applications: "*Making new columns invisible means they won't be seen by any existing applications, but can still be referenced by any new applications, making the migration of applications much simpler*"[(link)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/invisible-columns-12cr1). So that seems promising. ArcGIS would have no way of finding an invisible column, not even with a `SELECT *`. So, if ArcGIS has no way of seeing an invisible column, then the column couldn't break ArcGIS.

Comment: For example, function-based indexes are supported in ArcGIS. There are technical articles with instructions for making them. When we create a function-based index, it creates a hidden virtual column automatically: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16835670/#Comment_16835670 Those hidden virtual columns don't break ArcGIS. So I don't see how a manually created hidden column would either.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, creating a invisible SDO_GEOMETRY column **doesn't** seem to be supported by Oracle 18c:

```
ALTER TABLE ST_GEOM_ROADS_SDO_INVIS 
        ADD SDO_SHP SDO_GEOMETRY INVISIBLE;

ORA-54041: Visibility of an abstract data type column cannot be changed.
54041. 0000 - "Visibility of an abstract data type column cannot be changed."
*Cause:  An attempt was made to alter the visibility of an abstract data type column.
*Action:  Specify the column visibility change with a supported data type.
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=93f75f2ceb2a22e3c9b3662da0a775ce)

---

[Idea: Support invisible SDO_GEOMETRY columns](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499116/idea-support-invisible-sdo-geometry-columns/)

[Support invisible abstract datatypes (such as invisible SDO_GEOMETRY)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499117/support-invisible-abstract-datatypes-such-as-invisible-sdo-geometry/p1?new=1)